# Advanced SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one table in my database that I want to update each year. I need to pull two of the column values from my asp.net page and populate the rest from my database already.

I have a budget table for each year, the year updates automatically on my page according to the month of the year. When the month changes to a specific month I need the stored procedure to update itself to add the budget items with a blank amount so that I can enter the amounts manually.

Old Data:

```
Year Code1 Code1Description Code2 Code2Description BudgetAmt($750.00) Initials
```

New Data:

```
NewYear Code1 Code1Description Code2 Code2Description BudgetAmt($0.00) Initials
```

This so that when I enter editmode on my gridview the codes will already be there just with blank *`budgetamt`* for me to update. Does this make sense? Is it something that is possible?

Comment: Search for `SQL Server Job`. I mean it. Seriously. Not a wordplay.

Comment: Curious: Why you have a table for each year instead of a year column? And no, it dont make sense. Set 0 default values instead and insert the records when you need to persist them.

Comment: It is only a column not a seperate table. The year will be pulled from a function on my page I just need sql to pull that year and create the records for that year when it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having the webpage call the stored procedure?  In which case simply create a table with the item codes you want to be populated:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_TemplateSPROC]
(@year as int) AS
    INSERT tbl_webpage (Year, code1, code1desc, code2, code2desc, spending, Initials) 
      Select 
         @Year [Year], code1, code1desc, code2, code2desc, 
         0 as spending, '' as Initials
      from tablewithcodesin
```

This, when called, would populate a table with the Year, codes, and zeros/blanks for you to fill in.

tablewithcodesin would just be Code1 Code1Description Code2 Code2Description

Comment: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.